# Keep Service in sync with Application

Tags: android, android-service

I am wondering what is the best way to keep a service running while the application is running (may be in background) and then the service stopping when the application has ended (the application in this case has completely stopped, not in the background).

Another sub-question is: How to stop a service when application stops?

I realize one solution is to use BoundServices but is this the best way or good enough?
For example if an activity binds a service and then the system kills the activity and brings
it alive again then how will the service behave? Or are there other issues I am not aware of?

What would be the best way to implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html. 
A bound service is the server in a client-server interface. A bound service allows components (such as activities) to bind to the service, send requests, receive responses, and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). **A bound service typically lives only while it serves another application component and does not run in the background indefinitely.**

You have two options to start the service:
1. bindService() to activity
2. startForeground() and bind while it runs

Option 1 will only run as long as the activity is in view and the runnable active. (example use would be to use service to download a file)
Option 2 will run as long as the application is running (even when the activity is in the background) This option requires that your service be listed in the notification bar.

You can have a service stop itself by calling stopSelf(int) (I dont think this works if a activity is currently bound) or you can call stopService() from an activity.

As for the system killing the activity question.... Without knowing what your service will be handling its hard to give advice on how to handle this situation. For the most part a service running in the foreground will be the last resource the system will try to reclaim. If the system kills the activity the services onDestory method will be called where you should do some clean up so that the next time it starts you can continue in a safe manor.

http://developer.android.com/images/service_lifecycle.png